# Fluid Layout Panel not expanding to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having trouble with my layout on my modal.  Basically I want a main panel, and a sidebar panel that will always stay the same height.  That is they will expand 100% height to the bottom of the container.  Any help would be appreciated!

```
@main {
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="modal hide" id="myModal">
        <!-- Main Window -->
        <div class="panel panel-primary span10" style="float:left">
            <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title">Pick Category</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="row-fluid text-center">
                    @for(cate <- cates) {
                        <div class="span3 fix">
                                <a href="@routes.Builder.pickItem(cate.id)" class="img-polaroid thumbnail"><img type="image" src="@routes.Assets.at(cate.getImageUrl())"></a>
                                <h4 class="@cate.getFontColor()">@cate.getName()</h4>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="footer">
                    <a href="@routes.Builder.setLocation()"><input type="image" src="@routes.Assets.at("img/arrow_left.png")" type="button"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Shopping Cart -->
        <div class="panel panel-primary span2" style="float:right">
            <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
                <h1 class="panel-title">Cart</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
                <h4>yoyoyo</h4>
                <h4>yoyoyo</h4>
                <h4>yoyoyo</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            slider.reloadSlider();
        });
    </script>
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Your left column should be float left, the right column should be float right.  After the ending div tag to the right column you should add `<div style="clear: both"></div>` or create a class and call that class in the div.

Comment: Updated the code above.  Still getting the same thing though.  I forgot to mention that it's using bootstrap for everything too.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by using this technique.

**CSS:**

```
.col{
    margin-bottom: -99999px;
    padding-bottom: 99999px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
}

.col-wrap{
    overflow: hidden; 
}
```

**CODE:**

```
@main {
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="modal hide clean" id="myModal">
            <div class="row-fluid col-wrap">

                <!-- Main Window -->
                <div class="panel panel-primary span10 col">
                    <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
                        <h1 class="panel-title">Pick Category</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row-fluid text-center">
                            @for(cate <- cates) {
                                <div class="span3 fix">
                                        <a href="@routes.Builder.pickItem(cate.id)" class="img-polaroid thumbnail"><img type="image" src="@routes.Assets.at(cate.getImageUrl())"></a>
                                        <h4 class="@cate.getFontColor()">@cate.getName()</h4>
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                            <a href="@routes.Builder.setLocation()"><input type="image" src="@routes.Assets.at("img/arrow_left.png")" type="button"></a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- Shopping Cart -->
                <div class="panel panel-primary span2 col" style="margin-left:10px">
                    <div class="modal-header panel-heading">
                        <h1 class="panel-title">Cart</h1>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked">
                          <li class="active"><a href="#">Turkey Hoagie</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">-Lettuce</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">-Mayo</a></li>
                          <li><a href="#">-Tomatoes</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>  
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```